# Control the logging frequency and contents when using wandb with HuggingFace

Tags: huggingface-transformers, wandb

I am using the `wandb` with my HuggingFace code. I would like to log the loss and other metrics. Now I have two questions

- How does `wandb` decide when to log the loss? Is this decided by `logging_steps` in `TrainingArguments(...)`？

```py
training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="test", 
                                  learning_rate=lr,
                                  num_train_epochs=n_epoch,
                                  seed=seed,
                                  per_device_train_batch_size=2,
                                  per_device_eval_batch_size=2,
                                  logging_strategy="steps",
                                  logging_steps=5,
                                  report_to="wandb")
```

- How do I make sure `wandb` log other metrics (for example, adding validation metrics after each epoch)? Does this happen automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it is dictated by the `on_log` event from the Trainer, you can see it [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/6b241e0e3bda24546d15835e5e0b48b8d1e4732c/src/transformers/integrations.py#L747) in WandbCallback

Your validation metrics should be logged to W&B automatically every time you validate. How often Trainer does evaluation depends on what setting is used for `evaluation_strategy` (and potentially `eval_steps` if `evaluation_strategy == "steps"`)